# Implemented formula using a separate class stops listview from showing (using sqlite database)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am working on an app, for which I have implemented a formula. I implemented it using a separate class called `MyViewModel` (not to be confused with android's viewmodel please). This class has a method which has the formula. Now, that formula receives the data from a `DBHelper` (sqlite database), in my `TaskSummary` class. However, the listview isnt visible in the activity at all. What might be the issue here? Please guide me.

Code for DBHelper Class :

```
package com.example.taskmasterv3;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "Subtaskdata.db", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("create Table Subtaskdata(subtaskname TEXT primary key, prihigh INTEGER, primed INTEGER, prilow INTEGER, timemore INTEGER, timemed INTEGER, timeless INTEGER, totalTime INTEGER, time INTEGER)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("drop Table if exists Userdetails");
    }


    public Boolean insertSubtaskData(String subtaskName, int prihigh, int primed, int prilow, int timemore, int timemed, int timeless, int totalTime, int time){
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put("subtaskname", subtaskName);
            contentValues.put("priHigh", prihigh);
            contentValues.put("priMed", primed);
            contentValues.put("priLow", prilow);
            contentValues.put("timeMore", timemore);
            contentValues.put("timeMed", timemed);
            contentValues.put("timeLess", timeless);
            contentValues.put("totalTime", totalTime);
            contentValues.put("time", time);


            long result = db.insert("Subtaskdata", null, contentValues);
            if (result < 0){
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            } }



    public Boolean updateSubtaskData(String subtaskName, int prihigh, int primed, int prilow, int timemore, int timemed, int timeless,int totalTime, int time){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("subtaskname", subtaskName);
        contentValues.put("prihigh", prihigh);
        contentValues.put("primed", primed);
        contentValues.put("prilow", prilow);
        contentValues.put("timemore", timemore);
        contentValues.put("timemed", timemed);
        contentValues.put("timeless", timeless);
        contentValues.put("totalTime", totalTime);
        contentValues.put("time", time);

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from Subtaskdata where subtaskname = ?", new String[]{subtaskName});
        if (cursor.getCount()> 0){
        long result = db.update("Subtaskdata", contentValues, "name=?", new String[]{subtaskName});
        if (result== -1){
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        } }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }}






    public Boolean deletedata(String subtaskName){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from Subtaskdata where subtaskname = ?", new String[]{subtaskName});
        if (cursor.getCount()> 0){
            long result = db.delete("Subtaskdata","subtaskname=?", new String[]{subtaskName});
            if (result == -1){
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            } }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }}




        public Cursor getdata (){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from Subtaskdata", null);
        return cursor;
        }

        public void deleteAll(){

        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete("Subtaskdata", null, null);
        db.execSQL("delete from "+ "Subtaskdata");
        db.close();



        }



}
```

Code for MyViewModel Class (containing formula) :

```
package com.example.taskmasterv3;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyViewModel  {

    int timeInt;
    int totalTime;
    int timeConstant;
    DBHelper dbHelper;


    public int timeIntFinder(ArrayList<subtask> list,Context context) {

        dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getdata();

        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){

            timeInt += list.get(i).getTime();
        }

        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            totalTime = list.get(0).getTotaltime();
            timeConstant = totalTime / timeInt;
        }
        return timeConstant;
    }
}
```

Code for TaskSummary Class :

```
package com.example.taskmasterv3;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class TaskSummary extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lvTaskList;
    TextView tvBreak, tvBreakAfterEvery, txt1, txt2, text1, hmm;
    TextView break_duration_mins;
    ArrayList<SubtaskPartTwo> subtaskList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<subtask> listForTime = new ArrayList<>();
    //String subtname;
    //String pri;
    //String time;
    int working_hours;
    int working_minutes;
    int totalTime;
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    int timeInts;
    int timeConstant;
    int answer;
    int timetmetc;
    boolean looponeran = false;


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.tasksummary, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        dbHelper.deleteAll();

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.restore) {
            Intent inti = new Intent(this, TaskInfo.class);
            startActivity(inti);

        }



        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_task_summary);

        timetmetc = getIntent().getIntExtra("time", 1);




        MyViewModel myViewModel = new MyViewModel();


        lvTaskList = findViewById(R.id.lvTaskList);
        tvBreak = findViewById(R.id.tvBreak);
        tvBreakAfterEvery = findViewById(R.id.tvBreakAfterEvery);
        txt1 = findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        txt2 = findViewById(R.id.txt2);
        break_duration_mins = findViewById(R.id.break_duration_mins);
        text1 = findViewById(R.id.text1);
        hmm = findViewById(R.id.hmm);
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);

        working_hours = getIntent().getIntExtra("working_hours", 1);
        working_minutes = getIntent().getIntExtra("working_minutes", 0);
        timeConstant = getIntent().getIntExtra("timeconstant", 1);
        int alol = working_hours * 60;
        int blol = working_minutes;
        totalTime = alol + blol;
        double without_break_hours = getIntent().getIntExtra("without_break_hours", 1);
        double without_break_minutes = getIntent().getIntExtra("without_break_minutes", 0);
        double break_duration = getIntent().getIntExtra("break_duration", 20);
        String a = working_hours + " h";
        txt1.setText(a);
        String b = working_minutes + " m";
        break_duration_mins.setText(b);
        String c = break_duration + " m";
        txt2.setText(c);



        //Mathematics

        double g = working_hours * 100;
        double h = g + working_minutes;
        double i = h + break_duration;
        double j = i / 60;
        double p = (int) j;
        double q = j - p;
        double r = q * 60;

        without_break_hours = p;
        without_break_minutes = r;

        String d = without_break_hours + " h";
        String e = without_break_minutes + " m";

        text1.setText(d);
        hmm.setText(e);


        Cursor res = dbHelper.getdata();

        while (res.moveToNext()){

            looponeran = true;

            subtask subtask = new subtask("not req", false, false, false, false, false, false, timetmetc, totalTime);
            listForTime.add(subtask);
        }


        MyViewModel myViewModel1 = new MyViewModel();
        myViewModel1.timeIntFinder(listForTime, this);



// possible error : both the while loops run together causing null data being passed to database hence it isnt showing.
        // find a way to make the above while loop run first, and only after that the 2nd one should run or something..



        SubtaskDetailAdapter adapter = new SubtaskDetailAdapter(this, subtaskList);
        lvTaskList.setAdapter(adapter);



        while (res.moveToNext() && looponeran){

            looponeran = false;

            SubtaskPartTwo subtaskPartTwo = new SubtaskPartTwo(res.getString(0), res.getInt(1), res.getInt(2), res.getInt(3), res.getInt(4), res.getInt(5), res.getInt(6), 0, res.getInt(8), totalTime, timeConstant);
            //subtaskList.add(subtaskPartTwo);

            adapter.addANewSubTask(subtaskPartTwo);
        }



    }



}
```